# Counting commas in a line in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Sometimes I receive a CSV file which has a carriage return inside a cell. This is not an acceptable format to a program that will use it as input.

In order to detect if an input line is split, I determined that a bad line would not have the expected number of commas in it. Is there a bash or other common unix command line tool that would allow me to count the commas in the line? If necessary, I can write a Python or Perl program to do it, but if possible, I'd like to add a line or two to an existing bash script to cause it to fail if the comma count is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you just search for carriage returns and delete them?

Comment: I assume the asker means line breaks in general, and "just deleting them" won't work, as valid lines also end in a line feed character.

Comment: `a,b,"c,d,e"` has 3 fields but 4 commas

Answer (score 65):

Strip everything but the commas, and then count number of characters left:

```
$ echo foo,bar,baz | tr -cd , | wc -c
2
```

Comment: What's the runtime on this?

Comment: This assumes you are echoing the line, and not the file, right?
`echo "foo,bar,baz\nbaz,foo,foobar,bar" | tr -cd , | wc -c` produces `5`, instead of `2` and `3`.

Answer (score 14):

To count the number of times a comma appears, you can use something like awk:

```
string=(line of input from CSV file)
echo "$string" | awk -F "," '{print NF-1}'
```

But this really isn't sufficient to determine whether a field has carriage returns in it. Fields can have commas inside as long as they're surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me better than the other solutions was this.  If `test.txt` has:

```
foo,bar,baz
baz,foo,foobar,bar
```

Then `cat test.txt | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo % | tr -cd , | wc -c'` produces

```
2
3
```

This works very well for streaming sources, or tailing logs, etc.

Comment: I tried this and some of the lines got executed and the shell raised an error that the values were not found... Something not right with this one

Answer (score 5):

In pure Bash:

```
while IFS=, read -ra array
do
    echo "$((${#array[@]} - 1))"
done < inputfile
```

or

```
while read -r line
do
    count=${line//[^,]}
    echo "${#count}"
done < inputfile
```

Comment: wont work if a comma is contained in a quote delimited value.

Comment: @kiddouk: That's true of most of the other answers. If the data contains commas inside quoted fields, you'll need to use a tool which is made specifically for CSV files. The [Python csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) is an example.

Answer (score 3):

Try Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print 0+@{[/,/g]},"\n"'
a
0
a,a
1
a,a,a,a,a
4
```

Comment: You can coerce it to a scalar more easily by appending the newline: `print @{[/,/g]} . "\n"`

Comment: Using perl is...an interesting choice.  If I were going to use perl, I think I'd go with: `perl -F, -anE 'say $#F'`.  But this is a novel solution...so +1!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do with the CSV data, it may be helpful to use a wrapper script like csvquote to temporarily replace the problematic newlines (and commas) inside quoted fields, then restore them. For instance:

```
csvquote inputfile.csv | wc -l
```

and

```
csvquote inputfile.csv | cut -d, -f1 | csvquote -u
```

may be the sort of thing you're looking for. See `[https://github.com/dbro/csvquote][1]` for the code and more information

Answer (score 0):

An example Python command you could run (since it's going to be installed on most modern shells) is:

`python -c "import pathlib; print({l.count(',') for l in pathlib.Path('my_file.csv').read_text().splitlines()})"`

This counts the number of commas per line, then makes a set from them (so if your lines all have the same number of commas in, you'll get a set with just that number in).

Answer (score -2):

Just remove all of the carriage returns:

```
tr -d "\r" old_file > new_file
```

Comment: downvote because the carriage return is valid if it delimits records within the file, so they can't just be removed.